# How to view flask params in browser

Tags: python, flask

In Ruby on Rails I can type `fail` in the controller then go to the browser and view the list of params. How can I do that in flask(python) ?

Comment: Flask-DebugToolbar is probably the package you need. It can view the list of variables injected into jinja template

Comment: @LeonF yes that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mode debug, like below:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Now, you will be able to see any error from your browser.